# How to avoid UTF8 characters inside my NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

i'm saving a `NSString` inside an `NSArray` and that `NSArray` inside an `NSDictionary`. While doing this, a process inside my `NSDictionary` notifies me if my string is like `Hi I'm XYZ`. Then in the place of single quote the appropriate UTF character is getting stored.

So how to avoid this or how can I get my actual text along with special characters from `NSArray` or from my `NSDictionary`?
Any help is thankful.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use proper punctuation and capitalization in your questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

NSString internally uses Unicode characters. So it easily can handle all sorts of characters from different languages.

You cannot choose the internal encodig of NSString. It's always Unicode. If you have an encoding problem, then you have either created the NSString instance incorrectly or you have output the instance the wrong way.

And there's no such thing as an UTF character.

Please better describe your problem and show the relevant source code.